# mod_headers not working for php + mod_fastcgi pages

Tags: php, fastcgi, apache-2.2

I'm running PHP through mod_fastcgi & mod_suexec, and I added `Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge env=best-standards-support"` to my .htaccess file. It works fine for static content, but the PHP files lack the header. How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try `Header always set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge env=best-standards-support"`.

Please note that such a header isn't saved into the files, rather into the HTTP response environment.

If the above doesn't work, try to grab the HTTP response with either `curl -I exampmle.org` or for example a Firefox Addon called [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829/) to se if it's set.

Comment: always doesn't help, and I've already verified that the header is in fact not being sent with curl.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question, but since I couldn't find the answer anywhere online, I am posting it here: FastCGI looks for the .htaccess where its binary is located.

Depending on your directory structure, you might want to put the .htaccess file in FastCGI's directory or somewhere closer to the filesystem root directory from its location.